# comment-reply.js disables any other form javascript

Tags: jquery, javascript

I want to add autosize.js to the form textarea (#comment) but if comment-reply.js is enabled no other javascript in the comments form works. Any idea why is this happening?

```
//Auto resise textarea
autosize( $("#comment") );
```

No errors in the console and works fine when comment-reply.js isn't enabled.

I also tried a simple test with a click event and it doesn't work also.

```
$("#comment").on( "click", function() {
    console.log("click");
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the JS console?

Comment: @RRikesh no errors

Comment: Downvoted as "I have some code that doesn't work, but I am not going to tell you what is it" type of questions get boring very fast

Comment: @MarkKaplun sorry abou that I'll edit it but there isn't much code to show

Comment: why do you think that a script disables others ? explain what you know I you want that we help you

Comment: @mmm added more information, does it help?

Comment: now you starting to get there, pity a downvote was needed :(. are you sure your textarea has a "comment" id? have you removed the comment-reply.js and actually saw that your click script works after that?

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes the textarea has the id "comment". And I'm testing with two same forms one with comment-reply.js and one without one works the other doesn't.

Comment: have you switch to default theme and turned off any plugins?

Comment: @MarkKaplun thanks for all the help but I found the (dumb) mistake. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cuplrit and has nothing to do with comment-reply.js.

I was targeting my javascript based on which template and of course the javascript wasn't loading.

```
if( $("body").hasClass("page") ){ ...
```

Needed to add this:

```
if( $("body").hasClass("page") || $("body").hasClass("single") ){ ...
```

Comment: happens to all of us. The take away should be that when you ask a question here make a minimal "prof of bug" snippet to post here. This problem would have been spotted by you while doing that, or spotted by someone else almost immediately.

Comment: @MarkKaplun point taken!